# Code for quasi-Gaussian model (Cheyette model)

Tags: interest-rates, calibration, local-volatility, codes

I'm looking into the quasi-Gaussian model with linear local volatility as explained by Andersen and Piterbarg (Interest Rate Modeling, Volume 2). I'm trying to calibrate this model and implement it. I wonder if any of you knows where I can get a C++ or Matlab code for such model.

Many thanks

Comment: or in c#, it could be interesting too.